# java - check String contents

Tags: java

I need to perform the following check:

IF myString.contains()

ANY CHARACTERS OTHER THAN

letters a-z, A-Z, "_", "-", numbers 0-9

THEN .....

whats is the correct java syntax for such a check?

Comment: You could use a regex to split the string on those characters and check whether the resulting groups are non-empty.

Comment: The typical Java programmer will probably use a suitable regex pattern match, no?

Answer (score 11):

You could use a regular expression

```
Pattern badChar = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9_-]");
if(badChar.matcher(myString).find()) {
  // ...
}
```

This pattern will match any single character apart from letters, numbers, underscore and hyphen.

Comment: I'm not very good with regexes, so I'm curious: does the last "-" really need no escaping? Seems a bit odd to me if so since that would mean it's interpreted as a literal there whereas in "A-Z" it's interpreted as syntax.

Comment: @G.Bach yes, a hyphen _between two other characters_ denotes a range, but at the beginning or end of a character class expression it is a literal hyphen.

Comment: this works, thanks. BTW, would it work with cyrillic characters?

Comment: @IanRoberts This means that usually hyphens require escaping, the exception being if they are at the beginning or end of a group of the regex?

Comment: @Maver1ck a cyrillic letter is not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, underscore or hyphen so if `myString` contains one then `find` would return true.  If you want to allow non-Latin letters you could use `"[^\p{L}0-9_-]"` - `\p{L}` matches any character that is a "letter" according to the Unicode standard.

Comment: @G.Bach hyphens are only special as part of a range expression inside square brackets, they don't need to be escaped anywhere else but it won't do any harm (other than to the readability of the expression) if you do escape them.

Comment: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: @Maver1ck sorry, I forgot you need to double the backslash: `"[^\\p{L}0-9_-]"`.  That's the trouble with regular expressions in Java string literals, if you want a backslash character as part of the regex you need two backslashes in the string literal. I'm too used to Groovy, where you can use `/.../` for string literals that don't need the backslashes doubling.

Answer (score 1):

```
myString.matches("[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]*");
```

Comment: You probably want to add a `*` or `+` to that to allow for a string with more than one character.

Comment: @IanRoberts I just realized that, I was also forgetting to negate the content.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This Will Do it

String str1 = "abc,pqr";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9._,-]+");

```
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher(str1);
    System.out.println(matcher1.matches());
```